# Windows 10 stuck on safe mode

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode, msconfig, unresponsive

I am trying to access safe mode to experiment with a few things but all I'm getting is a black screen and the mouse switching from the loading cursor to arrow.

I set it to boot to safe mode via MSCONFIG thinking it was the Advanced Setting Menu and now I can't exit the safe mode.

Comment: It doesn't sound like it will be possible to access Safe Mode.  The only other thing you can attempt to do is cause Windows to fail to load three times in a row.  This will allow you to access Advanced Startup.  However, you are already accessing safe mode, whatever is wrong with your system is effecting safe mode as well.

Comment: I can use Windows normally but can't use safe mode. I was get out of it using said method and using CMD. Then I typed bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safemode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in an infinite boot loop and safe mode doesn't load, this is what you do.

1. Hard power off 3 times until you  get the Automatic System Repair
2. Click Advanced Options > Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > CMD
3. Type `d:`
4. Type `bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot`
5. Type `exit`
6. Click Continue

Comment: This prevents you from booting into Safe Mode but it doesn't solve your problem.  Unless I am mistaken and you no longer have a problem?

Comment: I am making it a separate question. I figured it would be easier to get answers that way as the title for this one doesn't mention it does not load. I needed to get out of safe boot first (as I set it to do it) in case I needed to remove anything that could cause it.

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLVED]**

I had the same problem trying to input the password I usually use for log in in my computer.

**You need to input the password of your Microsoft Account**, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Type `System Configuration` in the start menu.

In the dialog that comes up, go to the `Boot` tab, and unselect `Safe boot`. Then it will prompt you to restart the system.

[image]

Comment: The thing is... I can't access that. I boot up in safe mode to a black screen with the cursor trying to loading something. No explorer or taskbar.

Comment: @Bobj2018 press Ctrl+Shift+Esc or Ctrl+Alt+Del to run task manager, then run > new task. And did you try Win+R?

Comment: Hmm, no I haven't. I'll try that and get back with you.

Comment: It did not work, the only thing showing on the screen is the mouse. I would really like to have safe mode to work correctly.

Comment: @Bobj2018 do you have a dedicated graphics card or are you using integrated?

Comment: Also what happened when your tried Win + R?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to use the keyboard. I was able to get out of safe mode via automatic system repair then went to CMD and did BCDEdit /deletevalue {default} safemode in the D drive

Comment: @Bobj2018 I’m glad you got it. I was going to give the cmd command if you were able to get that the show up. The next route would have been what you did. Now double check that the safe boot is not checked lol.

Comment: I am now trying to figure out why safe mode isn't working.

Comment: @Bobj2018 - Don't take this the wrong way, you likely have an application installed (or a driver) that is causing the problem, hence the reason Windows is unable to fully boot (hence the black screen with a loading cursor).  You can attempt to roll back to a previous configuration, however, even that might not work

Comment: I thought startup programs were temporarily disabled in safemode .